# Given array, write function to return matching items

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to write a function, priceFilter(items, num) that returns an array of items that have a price below an input amount. And if there are no items have a price below the amount, my function should return an empty array.

Example output:

```
priceFilter(items, 50) //*   
[
  {
    itemName: "Effective Programming Habits",
    type: "book",
    price: 13.99
  }
  {
    itemName: "Finding Your Center",
    type: "book",
    price: 15.00
  }
]
*/
```

Given array:

```
let items = [
  {
    itemName: "Effective Programming Habits",
    type: "book",
    price: 13.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Creation 3005",
    type: "computer",
    price: 299.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Finding Your Center",
    type: "book",
    price: 15.00
  }
]
```

What I have so far:

```
function priceFilter(items, num) {
  var results = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (num > items.price) {
      return results.push(items);
    }
  }
}
```

I thought I could create an empty array, loop through then push it to the empty array but I'm not sure how to push (if .push() is even the right method) the entire item to the array.

Comment: push Does add them to the array, but you should only return the array after the iteration is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return `result` outside the `loop`

```
function priceFilter(items, num) {
  var results = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (num > items[i].price) {//also to make sure get each element
     results.push(items[i]);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, that makes sense. But my result comes back with an empty array

Comment: @alexwhitmore Sorry,I have updated my answer,you can re-check it now

Comment: Ahhh that's it! I put [i] in the wrong spot earlier. SO close, yet so far.. I appreciate all your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing that to `items[i].price` because items would return an ARRAY so you cannot get `items.price` since the price is inside the array.

right now, your `items` is actually `[{}, {}, {}]` so you cannot do `items.price`. You have to get the nth item of the array to access its price.

Answer (score 0):

```
> items.filter(item => item.price < n)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method to do this job.

```js
let items = [
    {
      itemName: "Effective Programming Habits",
      type: "book",
      price: 13.99
    },
    {
      itemName: "Creation 3005",
      type: "computer",
      price: 299.99
    },
    {
      itemName: "Finding Your Center",
      type: "book",
      price: 15.00
    }
  ]

  function filterItems(items,num){
    var newArray = items.filter(el => {
        return el.price < num;
    })
    return newArray;
  }

  console.log(filterItems(items,50));
```